# How can I create an element in HTML/CSS with a semicircle border at the top?

Tags: html, border, geometry, css

I want to create an element in HTML/CSS like the following:

[image]

Basically, I want to create a semicircle in the top-middle with a border around it and then have a smaller circle within that semicircle with a single character centered within it (like the X in the image above). Also, within this element, there might be any amount of text/images, etc.

Any help on the best way to create this type of element would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: would you be fine with an element for the box and a separate element for the circle?

Comment: Absolutely. I'm simply hoping for the easiest way to create this in HTML/CSS that works in most browsers, even if that means separate elements for the various parts. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with absolute positions and sizes:

**EDIT:**

Getting rid of the weird border effect on the circle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9JFpu/

It uses more css's and more html tags, but it solves the problem!
*Note: the code is a bit messy, it could be beautified!*

---

http://jsfiddle.net/D3tKE/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mySuperFancyEffect">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="inner-circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mySuperFancyEffect {
    position: relative;
}

.mySuperFancyEffect .square {
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #66C;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.mySuperFancyEffect .circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #66C;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

.mySuperFancyEffect .inner-circle {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #DAA74C;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

Comment: That is a simple and effective solution. Thank you. However, my one gripe is that the border for the large purple circle looks weird because it fades away as it gets closer to the border of the rectangle. Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: Yes! Please read my edit... It has more code, (html and css) but it solves the weird fade effect :)

Comment: Good answers. Thanks a lot for describing the simple way and the more complete and better looking way; and both with Fiddles!

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part here was making the semi-circle on top.
You just make the height half of the width and only set the first 2 values of the border-radius.

[image]

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9JFpu/4/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">X</div>
    Text here
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.outer
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: lightBlue;
    position:relative;
    margin: 50px;

    font-size: 42px;
    text-align: center;

}
.outer:before
{
    content: '';
    width: 48px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    top: -24px;
    z-index: -1;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius: 24px 24px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: lightBlue;
}
.inner
{
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    line-height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    top: -22px;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius: 22px;
    border: 2px solid lightBlue;
    font-size: 32px;
    background: orange;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This is a very good answer. I gave correct-answer credit to Toni Almeida because he answered first with two different and useful answers. Also, one of his answers is very similar to yours, although your answer is very good as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this CSS

```
#circletop{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-top-left-radius:100px;
    border-top-right-radius:100px;
}
```

here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vn72m/) to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
#rectangle {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    }

#circle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 5%;
    top: -2%;
    left: 48%;
    border-radius: 800px;
    background: orange;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: What do `#rectangle` and `#square` correspond to?